# Fragment Specific Actionbar MenuItems

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm building an application with ActionBarSherlock that uses the Dropdown list navigation style. I have it set that each dropdown list item loads a different fragment, and that works fine. What doesn't work is the menu items in the actionbar. I have `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in the fragments that I want to have menu items, as well as

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu, menu);
}
```

for the menus in the fragments. Every time I change fragments, I don't want the menu items appended which is what's happening. When one fragment is selected, the menu loads fine, then a different fragment is selected that isn't supposed to have menu items, and the menu items are the same as the previous fragment. Then if I go back to the first fragment, the menu items get doubled because they keep getting appended. How can I control this?

Answer (score 0):

In the normal case the menu shouldn't be appended. What does your menu.xml look like? Do you have id's set? Maybe creating a menu in the Activity?

Comment: heres a menu.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/fragment_menu_refresh"
        android:title="@string/refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
        android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>

and I want the items fragment dependent because I don't want to overcrowd the bar in a fragment that doesn't need the items

Comment: Do you other menu's have the same id's? I think that would be the issue.

Comment: all of the menu items have different id's and all of the menu.xml's have different names

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I wasn't using `FragmentTransaction` to load the fragments.

Comment: Made me curious...how did you do it then ;)

Comment: Well I programmatically created LinearLayout to contain the fragments and when the dropdown list was updated to a new position it recreated this view every time with the "createUI()" method. I don't recommend it since there is such a thing as FragmentTransaction. I have no idea how I missed it.